# How to assign a keyboard shortcut for a Nemo script

Tags: nemo

It may be redundant but I couldn't find the answer how to assign custom keyboard shortcut to run a Nemo script. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok, I have found /home/<user>/.gnome2/accels/nemo where keyboard shortcuts are stored. However, whichever shortcut key I assign for my script(s) is reset to blank. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I've realized my mistake. I haven't deleted the comment sign ";" at the beginning of the accelerators. Now all shortcuts for my scripts are working.